# Bash Command Line In-Line Array

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface

Any bash gurus know how to turn the commands below into a one liner?

```
trutch:$ touch app/views/pages/_sponsors.html.erb
trutch:$ touch app/views/pages/_donations.html.erb
trutch:$ touch app/views/pages/_volunteers.html.erb
```

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
trutch:$ touch app/views/pages/[ARRAY].html.erb
```

If you have any sources for bash tricks such as this it would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple bash lists can be used for this:

```
touch app/views/pages/_{sponsors,donations,volunteers}.html.erb
```

Have a look at [Bash One-Liners](http://www.bashoneliners.com/) for tips, but the man page is also pretty detailed.

Comment: Thank you very much. Also, thanks for the very kind RTFM :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want this:

```
touch app/views/pages/{_sponsors,_donations,_volunteers}.html.erb
```